# Конвертация  void* в byte[]

Tags: pinvoke, c++, c#

Пишу обёртку на С# для статической С++ библиотеки. С C++ не знаком. В unsafe контексте в параметре типа void* возвращается указатель на byte[]. Как этот массив выудить для дальнейшей обработки в C#? (Это текст который нужно преобразовать из ANSI в Unicode). Заранее благодарен.

Прототип:

```
MPFUN int MPAPI SignBufferEx(void **out_buf, int *out_len);
```

Вызов в работающей программе на C++:

```
void* buf = NULL;
SignBufferEx(&buf, &ln);
```

Вызов в моей:

```
[DllImport(pathdll)]
public static unsafe extern int SignBufferEx(void** out_buf, int* out_len)
```

Добавил код, но он возвращает не то, что ожидается :(

```
var buffor = new byte[ln];
var pBuffor = (byte*) buf;
for (var i = 0; i < ln; i++)
{
    buffor[i] = *(pBuffor+i);
}

Encoding textEnc = new UnicodeEncoding();
Console.Out.WriteLine("textEnc.GetString(buf) = {0}", textEnc.GetString(buffor));
sign = textEnc.GetString(buffor);
```

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос прототип функции, которая возвращает указатель на массив, а то сейчас не до конца понятно, что именно возвращается.

Comment: При преобразовании массива байт (если имеется в виду строка, т.е. char * в C++) в Unicode (в c# он наверное 2-х байтный) Вам надо учитывать  locale. Сам массив это просто идущие подряд байты. Берете по одному и преобразуете в два байта.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Мой код оказывается работает. Нужно было в base64 преобразовывать перед конвертацией в юникод - но это уже другая история. Всем спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте вместо `void** out_buf` использовать `ref IntPtr out_buf` в объявлении функции;

```
[DllImport(pathdll)]
public static extern int SignBufferEx(ref IntPtr out_buf, ref int out_len)
```

а после вызова функции

```
int result = SignBufferEx(ref out_buf, ref out_len);
```

и получения адреса строки в `out_buf`

```
string out_str = Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(out_buf);
```